# Insert into breaking alter table statement

Tags: sql

For some reason, my insert into statement seems to be stopping my alter table statement from running. When I delete it the column is added, but when I add it back it says the column hasn't been added.

code below:

```
ALTER TABLE MODEL 
ADD MOD_WAIT_CHG INT(11) 

INSERT INTO MODEL (MOD_WAIT_CHG) 
VALUES (100);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score -1):

i think you forgot a semi comma

```
ALTER TABLE MODEL ADD MOD_WAIT_CHG INT(11);

INSERT INTO MODEL (MOD_WAIT_CHG) VALUES (100);
```